# A mysterious expression from a discriminant

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, fractional-calculus, discriminant

I recently investigated $\textrm{Discriminant}_u(\omega P(u) +(z-u)P'(u))$, where $P(u) := u^3 + au + b$ and $\omega$ is a real parameter (with $\omega\in(0,1)\cup(1,3)$) associated with the order of a fractional derivative. (This is a special case of the problem previously discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379712/discriminant-of-alpha-pu-z-u-pu).) In doing so, I came across the following expression (plus some additional terms) that looks quite striking, but I haven't been able to place it:

$$\frac{3a(b-z^3)}{(\omega-1)\,\lambda} + \frac{z}{\lambda^3}\left(a^2\lambda\left(1-\frac{1}{(\omega-1)^2}\right)-3bz\right)$$

Here $\lambda:= \sqrt[3]{\omega-3}.$ I'm wondering if anyone has seen this expression, or something sufficiently similar to it, in any other context.

Due to a natural change of variables used to arrive at the above expression (which reduces the constant part of the above discriminant to the discriminant of the polynomial $\widetilde{P}(u)$ below), the expression should possibly be thought of as the “image” of the polynomial

$$\widetilde{P}(u) := u^3 + \frac{a}{(\omega-1)\sqrt[3]{\omega-3}}u + \frac{b}{\omega(\omega-3)}$$

under some discriminant-like “function”.

Does the expression above look familiar, or is it perhaps some determinant involving the coefficients in $\widetilde{P}(u)$, and $z$? Alternatively, do you see some way to attack $\textrm{Discriminant}_u(\omega P(u) +(z-u)P'(u))$ directly?

Comment: This is mechanised in Maple. The command `with(RootFinding[Parametric]):DiscriminantVariety([3*a*z^3 + 3*b*omega*z^2 - a^2*(omega*(omega - 2) - 2)*z - 3*a*b*omega*(omega - 3) = 0], [z])` outputs $[[a],[4\,{a}^{6}{\omega}^{6}-24\,{a}^{6}{\omega}^{5}+3\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}
{\omega}^{6}+24\,{a}^{6}{\omega}^{4}+150\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{\omega}^{5}+
64\,{a}^{6}{\omega}^{3}-1539\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{\omega}^{4}+108\,{b}^{4}{
\omega}^{5}-48\,{a}^{6}{\omega}^{2}+5046\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{\omega}^{3}-
324\,{b}^{4}{\omega}^{4}-96\,{a}^{6}\omega-5577\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{\omega
}^{2}-32\,{a}^{6}]]
 $.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking what the discriminant of the above expression is. I'm trying to find out what the expression means, or where it comes from, other than the original discriminant that I evaluated. I'll update the question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: @FllYissetat: You exclude a part of the question with the polynomial $3az^3 + 3b\omega z^2 - a^2(\omega(\omega - 2) - 2)z - 3ab\omega(\omega - 3) = 0]$, not noticing it. I find it unfair. Regard.

Comment: @user64494: OK, fair enough. I thought it made the question unnecessarily confusing to include it, and that it's probably also the wrong polynomial to attack, but I think I found an acceptable compromise now. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Fll'Yissetat: I've read your post several times, and I still don't understand what the question is...

Comment: @AlexM. Hmm. How about "have you seen the expression $$\frac{3a(b-z^3)}{(\omega-1)\,\lambda} + \frac{z}{\lambda^3}\left(a^2\lambda\left(1-\frac{1}{(\omega-1)^2}\right)-3bz\right)$$ somewhere else, or can you think of some way to evaluate $\textrm{Discriminant}_u(\omega P(u) +(z-u)P'(u))$ for the given polynomial $P(u) = u^3 + au + b$?"

Comment: Hopefully it's more comprehensible now...

Answer (score 3):

It might be illuminating to write the discriminant as the resultant of your polynomial with its derivative. If I've done the algebra correctly (but please check), the discriminant that you're computing is
$$
\operatorname{Resultant}\Bigl( (\omega -3)u^3+3z u^2 + a(\omega -1)u+(az+b\omega ),\,
3(\omega -3)u^2+6z u+a(\omega -1) \Bigr).
$$
Then subtracting $\frac13u$ times the second polynomial from the first gives the resultant of two quadratics,
$$
\operatorname{Resultant}\left(z u^2 + \frac23a(\omega -1)u+(az+b\omega ),\,
3(\omega -3)u^2+6z u+a(\omega -1)\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting! The corresponding resultant when you start with $P(u) = u^4 + au^2 + bu + c$ instead, and subtract the analogous $u/4$-multiplied factor, is

$$\mathrm{Resultant}_u\left(zu^3 + \frac{1}{2} a(\omega-2)u^2+\frac{3}{4}\left(2 az+b (\omega-1)\right)u+(bz+c\omega),\:4(\omega-4)u^3 +12 zu^2+ 2a(\omega-2)u + (2az+b(\omega-1))\right)$$

Curious $2az+b(\omega-1)$ constant term (and coefficient).

Comment: The OP points out in an edit attempt that it should be a "$+$" instead of the current "$-$" in front of the rightmost term $a(\omega-1)$, in both formulae.